# How to pass a 'double*' to a class function, and apply that value to another 'double*' in that class

Tags: c++, pointers, argument-passing, dynamic-arrays, class-constructors

I am trying to pass a double* which holds an array of doubles, into the constructor of my class, and assign the value element for element.

Main:

```
int main()
{
    double* data = new double[4];
    data[0] = 1.1; data[1] = 2.2; data[2] = 3.3; data[3] = 4.4;

    Matrix a(2,2,data);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N, double* input_data)
{
    this->M = M;
    this->N = N;

    cout << "Matrix Constructor: M: " << M << "\tN: " << N << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            data[i*N+j] = input_data[i*N+j]; //***This is the problem***
        }
    }

}
```

Any attempt to index past `input_data[0]` in the constructor causes a crash. `data[]` can be accessed fine, and I can index past `input_data[0]` of data in my main function.

I'm assuming this should not be done this way, and would appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

Comment: How does your `Matrix::data` look like? Where and how is it initialized?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem in the code posted here.  Can you post your class definition?

Comment: @Griwes since it seems `data` is dynamically allocated (M and N are passed as parameters), this seems to be the problem - he's not allocating memory for it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I know, I was trying to put his mind into right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're not allocating memory for `data` in your constructor.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N, double* input_data)
{
   data = new double[M*N];
   //....
}
```

Comment: Very much obliged! Why am I incapable of spotting the smallest of errors >.< This is an overloaded constructor, and my original contains the allocation, so I have no excuse for missing this.

Comment: @LBHoward also, as LihO pointed out, don't forget to free the memory in the destructor.

Comment: It's all in place, just commented out in the actual file, though thank you both for the reminder, the frame of mind I am tonight I wouldn't be suprised if I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `data` is a member of `Matrix` class declared as `double*`.

You should allocate memory for this member in your constructor:

```
this->M = M;
this->N = N;
data = new double[M * N];
...
```

Don't forget to call `delete[] data;` in destructor. You should also call `delete[] data;` at the end of main.

Comment: Just for the sake of nit-picking, it's not *necessary* to call `delete[] data;` in `main()` since the memory will be released anyway.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: True, but I still recommend to call it. At least you will get used to cleaning up after yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocated the memory to store the data.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N, double* input_data)
{
    this->M = M;
    this->N = N;
    data = new double[N * M]; // Allocate space for N * M elements

    cout << "Matrix Constructor: M: " << M << "\tN: " << N << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
         {
             data[i*N+j] = input_data[i*N+j]; //***This is the problem***
         }
     }

}
```

In C++, in order to allow for dynamic arrays like that you need to explicitly say that data is an array of size `N * M`. Otherwise, you're assigning into an undefined location which can be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allocate memory for data? Can't see that anywhere. However, I would not even bother with a constructor like that. Just take the dimensions as parameters (or as template parameters, but that's another thing I guess) and use a std::vector. Initialize the vector with N*M elements and overload the operator () for element access:

```
double& operator () (std::size_t i, std::size_t j);
const double& operator () (std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone pointed out, you didn't allocate space for `data`. Additionally, you'll need to provide a useful destructor, copy-constructor, and assignment operator.

All of this mishigas goes away if you use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> data;
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N, double* input_data)
  : M(M), N(N), data(input_data, input_data+M*N)
{
  // No work required in here
}
```